# Why is my onClick handler firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a parent component `<FilterGroupSection>` which instantiates a collection of `<RuleGroup />` child components:

```
return Object.values(this.props.filterGroups).map(function(ruleGroup) {
    const key = ruleGroup.id;
    return (
        <React.Fragment key={key}>
            <RuleGroup
                id={key} 
                key={key} 
                deleteRuleGroup={(e) => this.deleteRuleGroup(key, e)}
            />
            <Grid.Row></Grid.Row> {/*empty row to create space between filter groups*/}
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}.bind(this))
```

This works fine and as expected.

I am having difficulty with the handler function being passed to the `<RuleGroup />`, `deleteRuleGroup={(e) => this.deleteRuleGroup(key, e)}`

In the `<FilterGroupSection />` component handler function is:

```
deleteRuleGroup(id, e) {
    console.log('delete rule group called')

    this.props.filterGroupDeleted({filterGroupId: id})
}
```

I commented out `this.props.filterGroupDeleted({filterGroupId: id})` and the behaviour was as expected which leads me to believe the function runs multiple times when the component is re-rendered.

In the `<RuleGroup />` component the deleteRuleGroup function:

```
<Button                   
    color={"teal"} 
    size={"tiny"}
    onClick={(e) => this.props.deleteRuleGroup(id, e)}
>
```

When clicking on the button, the handler function keeps being called until a *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* error is shown. How can I ensure that the handler function is called only once when the button is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the snippet of code where you're defining your `deleteRuleGroup` method please?

Comment: Side note: you should call it `onClick={(e) => this.props.deleteRuleGroup(e)}` or better `onClick={this.props.deleteRuleGroup}` since prop have only one argument e `deleteRuleGroup={(e)` and key is taken from const.

Comment: I would suggest passing the function without a callback in one of the components. So for example in the main component just pass `this.deleteRuleGroup` without the parameters and not as a callback.

Comment: And onother Side note: `deleteRuleGroup={(e) => this.deleteRuleGroup(key, e)}` this make no sens since `this` context will be function from map.

Comment: If I’m understanding right, you could try e.preventPropogation in the deleteRuleGroup click handler. This will prevent it from bubbling up

Comment: As @jcubic pointed out, you already bind the id of the FilterGroup in your RuleGroup, so you must not do it in your Button again.